# Datatable sScroll is creating duplicate datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grails, datatables

I am facing issue in Datatable sScroll Property.

I have defined the datatable in my html file like below

```
<table id="datatable" class="vrptTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> column1</th>
                        <th>Column 2</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

            </table>
```

and I am populating this datatable in my js file as below :

```
var options = new DataTableOptions($table, {
                "sAjaxSource" : ajaxSource,
                "sAjaxDataProp" : "aaData",
                "sScrollY":"200px"




            }).getOptions();
            $("#table").dataTable(options)
```

;

The problem is it's creating the vertical scroll bar but i can see 2 tables in HTML DOM. First one contains only header information and second datatable contains empty header and my data.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely normal behavior of jQuery DataTables. See [this official example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html), there are two tables - one for the header, another one for the body.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. May be i didn't explain my problem completely. I am using ColResiazble js library to drag the column to see the complete value of Column data. To achieve this I need only one table instead of 2 tables. Is there any way to achieve scroll on datatable without using this scrollY property. I tried wrapping the datatable into external div and provided the overflow property to div but that's also not working.

Comment: @NehaNarlawar, most likely these two features (scrolling and column resizing) are not compatible out of the box. You might want to try to catch column resize event in table body and replicate it in the header, but it's not an easy task.

Comment: Ya I agree I am trying to use my own scroll function for table body but it's not behaving same as the datatable's scroll function. Thanks a lot for your help.